# Reading file after downloading it from Dropbox Chooser

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I can open the Dropbox file browser and download a file as ResultType.FILE_CONTENT. I get then an absolute path similar to `file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/cache/tmp/ch/file-10.txt`

When I try to access it using `File f = new File(path)` I call `f.isFile()` and get False.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remove `file://` so the path started with `/storage/sdcard0...`